# Effect of ease-in-out does not work

Tags: html, css, image, css-transitions, css-transforms

I want to create an effect overlay ease-in-out but unfortunately does not working. Can you tell me what's wrong?

```css
.product-item-info{
  position:relative;
  width:600px;
}
.product-item-info:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  visibility: visible;
}
.product-item-info:after {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
  -webkit-transition: all 30s ease-in-out 30s;
  -moz-transition: all 30s ease-in-out 30s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 3s ease-in-out 30s;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="product-item">
        <div class="product-item-info">
           <img class="product-image-photo" src="http://stagepearl.weltpixel.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/8/image/600x600/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/1/0/10001-00001-os_03_grande_1.jpg" alt="Test22" width="600" height="600">
        </div>  
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Its working *fine* - you have different values for you `transition` *vendor prefixes*. I adjusted the transition to:

```
transition: all 3s ease-in-out 0s;
```

See demo below:

```css
.product-item-info {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
}
.product-item-info:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  visibility: visible;
}
.product-item-info:after {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 3s ease-in-out 0s;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="product-item">
    <div class="product-item-info">
      <img class="product-image-photo" src="http://stagepearl.weltpixel.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/8/image/600x600/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/1/0/10001-00001-os_03_grande_1.jpg" alt="Test22" width="600" height="600">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```